# Minimum number of bits to represent the result of an expression on variables of known size?

Tags: c, memory, assembly, binary, bit

I'm trying to learn more about how computers store memory. So I've found information on how to represent binary numbers or hexadecimal numbers, but I found a question asking:

```
Given three n-bit unsigned ints: x, y, z, what is the min # 
of bits required to represent x * y + z
```

So my thinking is: Do I have to just account for all three ints separately and do the math for the smallest possible numbers so for example 0 * 0 + 0

Or do I have to account for another variable n that is the result of the problem?

I'm having some trouble thinking this out.

Comment: Minimum bits to represent the result?  Or to actually represent *the equation*, in a form that would let you evaluate it for any given x, y, and z?  If the latter, how many other operators does your language support?  Or can you use just 2 bits to represent each of the four `+` `-` `*` `/` arithmetic operators?  Also: termilogy: it's not an equation, it's a formula.  (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/38155/what-is-the-difference-between-equation-and-formula)

Comment: Actually it's clear from the question text what you're actually asking, so I fixed the title to match.

Comment: Not really worth posting as an answer since it's also not what you meant to ask, but in a C implementation where `unsigned int` has n bits, **the C expression `x * y + z` also has a type of `unsigned int`, and thus requires n bits**.  C guarantees that operations on `unsigned` integer types wrap around the way you'd expect for n-bit binary arithmetic (unlike signed types, where overflow is undefined behaviour).  A standards-conforming C implementation can have any n>=16.  You probably shouldn't have tagged this C, and maybe said "integers" not "ints"; "int" often means a fixed-width type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of bits required is `n + n`. Taking an example using 8 bits and maximum unsigned values:

```
255 * 255 + 255 = 65280
```

The result is less then `65536` which would require more than 16 bits.

Comment: Or, in hexadecimal form, `0xFF × 0xFF + 0xFF = 0xFF × (0xFF + 0x01) = 0x100 × 0xFF = 0xFF00 < 0xFFFF`.

Answer (score 3):

Max value of an n-bit unsigned number is 2<sup>n</sup> - 1.

The max result of

> a*b + c

would be:

> (2<sup>n</sup> - 1)*(2<sup>n</sup> - 1)   + (2<sup>n</sup> - 1)
>
> (2<sup>2n</sup> - 2<sup>n</sup> - 2<sup>n</sup> + 1) + (2<sup>n</sup> - 1)
>
> 2<sup>2n</sup> - 2<sup>n</sup>

Therefore, since

> 2<sup>2n</sup> - 2<sup>n</sup>

is less than the maximum (2*n)-bit unsigned number: 2<sup>2n</sup> - 1, (2*n) bits will suffice to represent any answer.

Examples of how to code it

```
uint64_t ab_plus_c_bad(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c) {
  return a*b + c;  // potential overflow with product.
}

uint64_t ab_plus_c_good(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint32_t c) {
  // a is widened before the multiplication
  return (uint64_t) a*b + c;  // no product overflow
}
```

Comment: Great answer in that you provide the derivation to generalize the answer to any potential number of bits.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum value that can be represented is pow(2,n)-1.
and your equation yields (pow(2,n)-1) * (pow(2,n)-1) + (pow(2,n)-1)

So to find out how many bits are required

```
n |max val.| max eqn.   | req'd bits 
--|--------|------------|-----------
1 |   1    |  1*1+1=2   | 2
2 |   3    |  3*3+3=12  | 4
3 |   7    |  7*7+7=56  | 6
4 |   15   |15*15+15=240| 8
5 |   31   |31*31+31=992| 10
...see the pattern
```

To figure this out for *any* n, use something like this:

```
//This uses double since the loss of precision will be insignificant
//but covers a large range of n.
//There are more efficient ways for small values of n.
//long double could be used instead for REALLY large values of n
#include <math.h>
#define n 999UL

//the highest unsigned value that can be represented by n bits is:
double max_value = pow(2.0, (double)n) - 1.0;

//figure out the max value you can get with your equation
double max_eqn = max_value * max_value + max_value;

//take the log base 2 of that and round it up to get max bits
//note that log base x of n is equal to log(n)/log(x);
unsigned long req_bits = (unsigned long) ceil(log(max_eqn)/log(2.0));

printf("The maximum required number of bits for %ul bits is %ul", n, req_bits);
```